# React-Native Loading Class Object from AsyncStorage.getItem()

Tags: typescript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to load data from `AsyncStorage`, but I'm having trouble handling the data as classes. For instance:

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

function loadMyClass() {
  const myClass = new MyClass();

  AsyncStorage.setItem("@my.class", JSON.stringify(myClass)).then(() => {
    load<MyClass>("@my.class").then((mc) => {
      console.log("value:");
      console.log(mc);
      console.log("type:");
      console.log(typeof mc);
    });
  });
}

async function load<T>(key: string) {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then((json) => {
    if (json != null) {
      const obj = JSON.parse(json) as T;
      return obj;
    }

    return null;
  });
}

class MyClass {
  private value: string = "abc";
}
```

And then when I call `loadMyClass()`, I get this printed to the console:

```
value:
Object {
  "value": "abc",
}
type:
object
```

Where I expect to get this output:

```
value:
MyClass{
  "value": "abc",
}
type:
MyClass
```

How can I cast my plain objects to a class and use them as a class?

Also - I know of [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer), but I've ran into some issues with it that I don't like so I'd prefer a pure Typescript solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the Reactiflux Discord group, I got an answer. Basically during the transpilation, types are gone so there's no way to get it back to the original type from a plain object (without using `class-transformer` which I'd like to avoid).

Credit to Glinkis: https://discord.com/channels/102860784329052160/106513299905994752/952219227761303602

In my particular case, I was trying to store a class object so that I could have methods to modify its state; I will now, instead, store an interfaced object and use functions to modify the data.